# How does Zookeeper manage node roles in other clusters?

Tags: configuration, apache-zookeeper, distributed-computing

My understanding is that Zookeeper is often used to solve the problem of *"keeping track of which node plays a particular role"* in a distributed system (e.g. master node in a DB or in a MapReduce cluster, etc).

For simplicity, say we have a DB with one master and multiple replicas and the current master node in the DB goes down. In this scenario, one would, in principle, make one of the replica nodes a new master node. At this point my understanding is:

#### If we didn't have Zookeeper

The application servers may not know that we have a new master node, so they would **not** know where to send writes unless we have some custom logic on the app server itself to detect / correct this problem.

#### If we have Zookeeper

Zookeeper would somehow **detect** this failure, and update the value for the corresponding master key. Moreover, application servers can (optionally?) register hooks in Zookeeper, so Zookeeper can notify them of this failure, so that the app servers can update (e.g. in memory), which DB node is the new master.

---

My questions are:

1. How does Zookeper know what node to make master? Is Zookeper responsible for this choice?
2. How is this information propagated to nodes that need to interact with Zookeeper? E.g. If one of the  **Zookeeper nodes** go down, how would the application servers know which Zookeeper node to hit in this scenario? Does Zookeeper manage this differently from competing solutions like e.g. [etcd](https://etcd.io/)?

Comment: 1 and 2 both in m y point of view

Comment: @ShalithaJayamal Hmm ? Not sure I follow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to both 1. and 2. is called `leader election process` and briefly works in the following way:

When a process starts in a cluster managed by ZK, the cluster enters an `election` state. If there is a leader then there exists an established hierarcy and the existing leader is just verified. If there is no leader (say master is down), ZK forces the znodes to use sequence flags to look for a new leader. Each node talks to its peers and sends a message containing the node's identifier (sid) and the most recent transaction it executed (zxid). These messages are called `votes`. When a node receives a vote it can either neglect it or keep it depending the zxid. If zxid is newer it keeps the vote if older than what it has it discards it. If there is a tie in zxids then the vote with the highest sid wins! So there will come a time when all nodes will have the same vote which will define the new leader by the sid. So this is how ZK elects a new leader node!

Comment: Thanks! so can Zookeper actually be responsible for electing the master node for e.g. a database cluster? i.e. I'm not talking about electing a master or leader for Zookeeper itself, but a master for a **different cluster**, e.g. a database cluster with one master node and several read replicas. Can Zookeeper actually manage the election of masters for **other** clusters?  If so, do you have any links that provides evidence of the above, or ideally explain how this works, and for what type of clusters?

Comment: Yes to all your questions IF you configure ZK with your `cluster`. Here is a [link](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/current/zookeeperUseCases.html) with a list (from Apache) of many many projects ZK has been integrated with. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thx! so for me to get this right: On one hand, we have a ZK cluster which is a cluster that can be exclusively dedicated to running and hosting ZK itself. Then **separately**,  we may have other clusters that may be *managed by* ZK. This can be e.g. a DB cluster with master and slave nodes where we may want ZK to manage which node/s are "master" through the leader election process that you outlined above. Did I get this right? I ask because I *thought* that the *leader election process* that you mentioned above only applied to choosing a master in the ZK cluster, and not _other_ clusters.

Comment: Exactly, ZK is a coordination service for distributed systems, but also a distributed application on its own.

Now, say you manage a cluster with ZK (either an ensemble or a single ZK instance). This cluster (of client nodes) create different znodes that ZK manages. There is a hierarchy of these znodes and a variety of them (ephemeral, persistent, sequential). If a client of your cluster (that was declared as a master) dies, then the remaining znodes created by the rest of the client nodes are ordered by ZK and your cluster is re-synchronized.