# Can etcd detect problems and elect leaders for other clusters?

Tags: kubernetes, distributed-computing, etcd, raft

To my knowledge, `etcd` uses Raft as a consensus and leader selection algorithm to maintain a leader that is in charge of keeping the ensemble of `etcd` nodes in sync with data changes within the `etcd` cluster. Among other things, this allows `etcd` to recover from node failures in the cluster where `etcd` runs.

But what about `etcd` managing ***other*** clusters, i.e. clusters other than the one where `etcd` runs?

For example, say we have an `etcd` cluster and **separately**, a DB (e.g. MySQL or Redis) cluster comprised of master (read and write) node/s and (read-only) replicas. Can `etcd` manage node roles for this other cluster?

More specifically:

- Can `etcd` elect a leader for clusters **other** than the one running `etcd` and make that information available to other clusters and nodes?
- To make this more concrete, using the example above, say a master node in the MySQL DB cluster mentioned in the above example goes down. Note again, that the master and replicas for the MySQL DB are running on a different cluster from the nodes running and hosting `etcd` data.

  - Does `etcd` provide capabilities to detect this type of node failures on clusters other than `etcd`'s automatically? If yes, how is this done in practice? (e.g. MySQL DB or any other cluster where nodes can take on different roles).
  - After detecting such failure, can `etcd` re-arrange node roles in this separate cluster (i.e. designate new master and replicas), and would it use the Raft leader selection algorithm for this as well?
  - Once it has done so, can `etcd` **also** notify client (application) nodes that depend on this DB and configuration accordingly?
  - Finally, does any of the above require **Kubernetes**? Or can `etcd` manage external clusters all by its own?

---

In case it helps, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62392433/1732769)'s a similar question for Zookeper.

Answer (score 4):

etcd's master election is strictly for electing a leader for etcd itself.

Other clusters, however can use a distributed strongly-consistent key-value store (such as etcd) to implement their own failure detection, leader election and to allow clients of that cluster to respond.

Etcd doesn't manage clusters other than its own.  It's not magic awesome sauce.

If you want to use etcd to manage a mysql cluster, you will need a component which manages the mysql nodes and stores cluster state in etcd.  Clients can watch for changes in that cluster state and adjust.

Comment: Thanks @Levi - When it comes to those components to manage cluster state in `etcd`, do you know what type of support exists in the `etcd` ecosystem?  E.g. I see ZooKeeper [lists explicitly here](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/current/zookeeperUseCases.html) a set of projects that apparently have native support for it, i.e. they may detect and set keys in ZooKeeper automatically if configured properly. Are you aware of a similar type of support for any of those projects? (e.g. MySQL, Hadoop, Flink, Spark, etc) or is that missing in the `etcd` ecosystem? E.g. how would it work for MySQL?